# Django 404 error-page not found & No CSS renders

Tags: python, html, css, django

New-ish coder and first time stack overflow poster. I've made a django project with 3 pages. Sometimes **no pages are found**, sometimes the index page loads without 404 error but I can't link to other pages and the **css files I've pointed it to doesn't render**.

Errors I'm getting is:

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP91h.png)

I have slept on the problem, looked up file formats to make sure my project and app url.py is correct. added app to settings. imported correct classes.  I have also tried clearing my browser data on chrome and using a different browser.

If anyone could take a look at my small project on github that would be amazing. https://github.com/Connell-L/portfolio_website is the link or if anyone wants me to post code files on codepen or something I'm more than happy to do it.

Edit: https://github.com/Connell-L/portfolio_website/tree/branch1 it's here sorry lol

Comment: At first glance, the cause of the missing css might be the missing STATIC_ROOT. Try adding this after STATIC_URL: `STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))`

Comment: Your request urls seems off. It should be url, not template path.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT to your project settings.py

like this:

```python
 BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.
```

the above line of code has to be at the bigining of your settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

Comment: This worked for rendering the CSS, thanks very much. Changed my static folder to the root directory and did no subdirectory.